# Best practices for adding CSS to Shiny app and overriding defaults

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want the `dateRangeInput()` dropdown menu to be visible at all times.

The z-index for the navbar is higher than the default z-index for the dropdown menu, which can cause the date range menu to be hidden behind the navbar when it opens upwards:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        br(),
        dateRangeInput(
          "date",
          "Date"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: hidden date range input menu]

I tried adding `tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".dropdown-menu {z-index: 9999}")))`, but this gets overridden. Same is true of a dedicated styles.css.

So I can either use `tagAppendAttributes()`:

```r
 dateRangeInput(
          "date",
          "Date"
        ) %>% 
          tagAppendAttributes(style = "z-index: 9999;")
```

Or I can use `.dropdown-menu {z-index: 9999 !important;}` to ensure the z-index I want overrides all. I can include this in a dedicated CSS file.

[image: date range input not hidden]

My question is: Are there any other options? If not, which is preferred and why?

Comment: You may want to learn some [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) first. Then the conclusion is there is no best option, all rely on the framework, dependencies you are using. For example, one rule I personally follow is to never use `!important`, it will make the life of other developers who depend on your products much easier. However, not all developers respect it. There are many others use `!important` when they develop the framework, so when you use their framework and try to overwrite some styles, the only thing you left to say is Fxxx.

Comment: In your case, another possibility is the style is set by javascript, and you will never know it looks like until the app runs. This makes your life even harder. So the recommendation I would give is if you are the end-user, be careful when you choose your dependency, and as long as your code/style works, perfect world, who cares about how you made it work. If you are a developer and want to have other people to build on top of your things, be nice and think about other developers in advance.

Comment: @lz100 Thanks for your comments. Coming back to the specific example I provide, how would you approach the problem? (Assume you are building an app rather than a library meant to be used by other developers.) Would you use tagAppendAttributes() and call it a day?

Comment: I would use `tags$style` if no `!important` needs to be used, but if `tags$style` won't work, I would use`tagAppendAttributes` to avoid `!important`